# pip3 - 'not a supported wheel on this platform' error

Tags: centos, python3, pip

I am trying to install SIP through pip3 (which is required to install PyQt5).

`pip3 search SIP` show that there is a package named `SIP (4.19.8) - extension module generator for C and C++ libraries`.

`pip3 install SIP` gives the error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SIP (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for SIP`

I've downloaded and tried to install the following files using the command `python -m pip install 'package name.whl'`:

```
sip-4.19.8-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
sip-4.19.8-cp36-none-win32.whl
sip-4.19.8-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
sip-4.19.8-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
```

It says `(package name) is not a supported wheel on this platform.` for all four of the files.

I'm using Python 3.6.4 on CentOS7. The CPU is an Intel i7-3610QM.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
```

outputs `('64bit', 'ELF')`.

```
>>> import pip
>>> print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

outputs

`[('cp36', 'cp36dm', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp36', 'cp36dm', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp36', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp36', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp33', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp33', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp32', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp32', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('py3', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('py3', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py36', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]`

Why can't pip find a supported wheel? What package should I install?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this way solve your problem, but let's try.
You have `('cp36', 'cp36dm', 'manylinux1_x86_64')` but you need `(cp36, cp36mm manylinux1_x86_64)`.

EPEL release as far as I see has package names `python36-dm`, install it and check if it is working.

If not maybe try to rename whl file to follow your python config and check if it working.